# how to concat integer with rails tag?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

im trying to concat dynamic int in a rails tagging within erb. 
the main idea is to dynamically update the infobox text.

```
for (i=2;i<=numplayers;i++)
{
    document.getElementById("infobox2").innerHTML= '<%= @plrdet["+i+"].name %>';
}
```

if im trying somthing like

```
 document.getElementById("infobox2").innerHTML= '<%= @plrdet["+i+"].name %>';
```

it  sends error

```
can't convert String into Integer
```

tried alot of combinations, any idea?

Comment: I am assuming this is JavaScript inside a .js.erb file.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("infobox2").innerHTML= '<%= @plrdet["+i.to_s"].name %>';
```

but, it also looks like you want an index to an array, but are wrapping it in a string in that case you should just use:

```
document.getElementById("infobox2").innerHTML = '<%= @plrdet[i].name%>';
```

#### Update...

I believe the problem lies with that you are trying to execute ruby code when you want the JavaScript Variable.  I belive this may work.

```
document.getElementById("infobox2").innerHTML = "<%= @plrdet["+i+"].name%>";
```

notice the double quotes used instead of the single quotes and begining and end.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunetlty it doesnt work, it still send me the error
can't convert String into Integer
i tried with to_i as well with no luck

Comment: yes, i tried it as well

undefined local variable or method `i' for #<#<Class:0x007ff55433fff8>:0x007ff554557890>

Comment: @user1442066 Maybe you are looking for something like ```document.getElementByID("infobox2").innerHTML = "<%= @plrdet[#{i}].name %>```?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it the other way around. Your javascript code will be evaluated in the client browser, and `i` is not known until then. In theses conditions, `<%= @plrdet[i] %>` won't be evaluated by Rails.

```
<% for i in (0..numberofplayers) do %>
  document.getElementById("infobox2").innerHTML= '<%= @plrdet[i].name %>';
<% end %>
```

You'd have to be able to evaluate `numberofplayers` in ERB though.

Comment: sorry, but im newb in rails.

i tried to simplify is it as possible to :

    function createPie() {
       <% for i in (0..2) do %>
          document.getElementById("infobox2").innerHTML= '<%= @plrdet[i].name %>';
       <% end %>
}

Comment: bummer, i thought i had it.
still doesnt work

    function createPie() {
      <% for i in (2..@pool.num_of_players) do %>
        if (<%=i-2%> < <%= @plrdet.size %> ) {  
            document.getElementById("infobox2").innerHTML= "<%= @plrdet["+i+"].name%>";
    }
    <% end %>
    }

Comment: It should be
`function createPie() { 
   <% for i in (2..@pool.num_of_players) do %> 
     <% if i-2 < @plrdet.size %>
         document.getElementById("infobox2").innerHTML= "<%= @plrdet[i].name%>"; 
     <% end %>
   <% end %> 
}`
I tried it, it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=2;i<=numplayers;i++)
{  
    document.getElementById("infobox2").innerHTML = <%= @plrdet[i].name%>;
}
```